# bash/cygwin: on login cd to directory i was on last "exit"

Tags: bash, cygwin, cd

On cygwin start I'd like to be back in the same dir I was when left cygwin (by `exit`) last time.

So I think i need to store the current dir on `exit` in a file and use this to come back on next login in `.bashrc`.  Is there a default script called on `exit` or logout?

Comment: Try `.bash_logout` but be warned that things are a bit more complex than what you think...

Comment: `.bash_logout` is only for login shell. not sure if cygwin would invoke login shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
trap 'pwd > ~/.lastdir' EXIT
if [[ -f ~/.lastdir ]]; then
    cd "$(< ~/.lastdir)"
fi
```

Comment: This naively assumes that you only run a single Bash instance.

Comment: just for the OP to start from. we don't really know the real requirements. :)